# Laravel eloquent complex queries on relationships2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tables

```
Business
    id
    name

Portfolio
    id
    image
    description
    business_id
```

---

Models

```
class Business extends \Eloquent 
{
    public function portfolio()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Portfolio');
    }
}


class Portfolio extends \Eloquent {

   public function business()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('Business');
   }
}
```

Now i want to know is it possible if i have a portfolio id then get all the portfolios which belongs the same business id.

Comment: `Portfolio::find($id)->business()->portfolios` - notice you should put an s after portfolio, because a business can have many of them.

Comment: "Undefined property: Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\BelongsTo::$portfolio","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\iclubz\\app\\controllers\\PortfoliosController.php","line":54
this happand

Comment: @JoelHinz You've accidentally referenced the business relationship query instead of the retrieved object. @moinkhan, this is why you received the error you did. Correct usage would be to access the object: `Portfolio::find($id)->business->portfolio`.

Comment: Formatted the table names to make them more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the portfolio id, you first find the portfolio, then you get the business for that portfolio, and then you get all the portfolios for that business:

```
$portfolio = Portfolio::find($id);
$business = $portfolio->business;
$portfolios = $business->portfolio;
```

Or, with a one liner:

```
$portfolios = Portfolio::find($id)->business->portfolio;
```